# write from an html to another using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form written in html that contains a form. I must write another html page using javascript and it will contain the information that the user writes in the form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
```

I have already used `appendchild` but it doesn't accept the name of the button.

Comment: you must write another html page using javascript? do you mean another  html element?

Comment: for example the user write his name in the first page when he click submit, a pop up display show : the name you tapped on the text box is : Blabla. then I must close the popup using a button in the page.

Comment: @user3288339 Better avoid pop-ups. Most browsers will block them, and if not, they are really annoying.

Comment: okay can I at least use the information of the form then display them in another page html ?

Comment: @user3288339 why in another page? you can show the input text in another element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean get the value from FORM and show it in popup why don't u try this..

check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L226J/)

```
<html>
<script>
function f()
{
   var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
   var myWindow = window.open("","MsgWindow","width=400,height=100");
   myWindow.document.write("User Name = <b><i>"+name+"</i></b>.");
   return false;
}
</script>
<body>
  <form onsubmit="return f()" >
    <input type="text" id="name" />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If that's on the page itself then you can create a new html document using

```
document.createElement()
```

but if you want to do that in any other window, then that won't be possible. Since JavaScript can't handle the events on other windows.

For the method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement

Then you can append the text to it, using the values from the form.

Comment: okay thanks! I'll just do it inside the same html. thanks for the url !